# Keep session active after closing rdp

Tags: windows, windows-10, remote-desktop

I have a bit of a special situation here. We have a desktop connected to some lab equipment. Users will login remotely using remote desktop to use the lab equipment. Problem is when they trigger something by Jenkins for example they can't run the lab equipment because there is no user signed in and/or no active session. So I need to configure windows so that basically the user is always signed on and has an active session. Which also means that when the login by remote desktop and close the remote desktop session that the user should still be active. They use all the same user, a local user on that machine.

I already tried the following: https://www.anyviewer.com/how-to/keep-rdp-session-alive-0007.html

Anyone an idea on how to do this?
System => windows 10 pro

Comment: Does [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62216967/how-to-prevent-logging-out-losing-screen-after-closing-rdp) help?

Comment: We do this all the time at work, but it's with Windows Servers, by just close out of the remote desktop, not logging off. (Aka X out of RDP from the top bar.) You may have to look at the differences between Windows 10 Pro vs Windows Server when it comes to remote desktop. And another option would be to look at VNC.

Comment: I tried the options but it didn't work. As soon when i close the remote desktop connection the user is signed off... Is there no way to configure this with powershell?

Comment: You need Terminal Services.